# Как сохранять сессии в NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

Пишу свой клиент VK, заход осуществляется логином и паролем. При логине создается сессия в vk, правильно ли я понимаю что мне нужно дополнительно создавать сессию в своем Node  приложении, дабы при перезапуске приложения сессия не вылетала а сохраняла логин?

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от того, что вы хотите получить(очень широко спрашиваете). 
Свою сессию вы можете сохранить в куки или, если используете экспресс, воспользоваться отдельным [модулем](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)

Answer (score 0):

Если сессия должна храниться на сервере с защитой от перезапуска приложения - следует использовать хранилище типа Redis, которое будет хранить ваши данные в оперативной памяти и писать их на диск для защиты от перезагрузки.